# Creating a prompt that has a time delay?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a prompt that has a time delay, the value that is written in the prompt is then used in other areas of the form. I have written some javascript coding but I believe there is a minor thing that i am doing wrong as currently the prompt and delay are working, but because the setTimeout function is being used, that is what is being displayed in the form, instead of the content of the prompt. This is my Javascript?

```
var name = setTimeout(function(){ prompt("What is your name?", "Type your full name here")},750); 
document.write("Document Written By: " + name + " (" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + ") ")
```

Comment: What do you mean "prompt with time delay"? And for all that's holy, please stop using `document.write`.

Comment: A prompt box that appears on page load, I want it to have about a 1 second delay before appearing

Comment: Perhaps your question is not titled very well, since *the delay is working*. Matt's answer should cover the rest.

Comment: What is the issue of using document.write, can you reccommend alternatives

Answer (score 4):

If it depends on the value, and a function is asynchronous, you've got do it in the callback. Just like every other asynchronous piece of JavaScript...

```
setTimeout(function(){
    name = prompt("What is your name?", "Type your full name here");
    document.write("Document Written By: " + name + " (" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + ") ");
},750);
```

But as @Jon commented, [please do not use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Comment: Something still isnt quite right, by using this coding It takes what is written in the prompt box and displays it in a new tab, I wanted the contents of the prompt box to be written within the original body tags

Comment: Yup, don't use `document.write`.

Comment: can you recommend an alternative

Comment: Proper DOM manipulation APIs. Are you using jQuery or any other cross-browser library?

Comment: Nope, just straight JavaScript and HTML

Comment: Then straight DOM. Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.createTextNode and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild